# Syntax to extract variable labels from SPSS file

Tags: spss

I have hundreds of SPSS .sav files. For each one I want to extract the variable NAMES and variable LABELS as a two column table to a csv file. I know that this is straightforward by simply copying and pasting from the "Variable view" window, but I would really like to know how to do this using syntax. Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in the GATHERMD extension command,  It takes a wildcard for the file names and builds a dataset with three variables: the file name, the variable name, and the variable label.  You could then just save that as a csv file.

This command requires the Python Essentials available with your Statistics installation or via the SPSS Community website (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral).

Using native Statistics syntax, DISPLAY DICTIONARY and CODEBOOK might be helpful, but they won't give you all this information in one table.

Comment: Big thank you for replying. Just to note that I solved the problem using a perl script that I found online: [http://czep.net/data/spssread/](http://czep.net/data/spssread/)